# PCI definition of "store"

Tags: pci-dss

In the PCI DSS 3.1 requirements, the term "store" is used often.  For example requirement 3.2 says "Do not store sensitive authentication data after authorization (even if encrypted)..."  Does this mean sensitive authentication data can be kept in memory and even transmitted between systems after an authorization or is the use of memory (RAM) considered storage?

Answer (score 5):

IANAQSA

**In the PCI DSS, "store" basically means "keep a copy of, outside of those copies which are necessary to the actual processing chain."**  It's not so much the method of "storage" as the intent.

So the [SAD](http://blog.elementps.com/element_payment_solutions/2013/03/what-are-sensitive-authentication-data.html) may be kept in memory, written to a database, or even saved to a file *as a necessary component of processing.*  Batch processing files are the most obvious example of this.  I have heard QSAs describe the acceptable period for this processing-storage state as "hours, not more than 24"; here's a [snippet from Braintree](https://www.braintreepayments.com/blog/pci-compliance-and-temporarily-storing-the-cvv2-value/) claiming that it might be up to days.  You should discuss your situation with your QSA; they are the only ones whose opinion matters.

Likewise, if you are keeping the SAD in memory after it was no longer necessary for processing, you're violating the "do not store" clause.  You could, hypothetically, set up a pair of programs to ping-pong the SAD data across the network so that it was always being transmitted; if you didn't need that data for a processing step, you're still "storing" it when you shouldn't be.

Comment: A good answer.  RAM=non-storage; anything else=storage  is a good rule of thumb in most situations, but there are definite exceptions on both sides. The ping-pong hypothetical is something I've never thought of before. (The obvious RAM-is-storage case is where data is just "forgotten about" in a server's RAM by an application and might just stay there, ripe for plucking, until however long it takes before the server happens to get rebooted.)   Interesting...